# Apache mod_rewrite internally to different port

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to internally redirect (so url won't change in address bar) with mod_rewrite to different port on same host?
Eg

```
http://host.com:8080 -> http://host.com:9999/myapplication/?param=val
```

Comment: look at `mod_proxy` .. as well as `[P]` (Proxy) flag of RewriteRule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1, Enable mod_proxy

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

2, You should configure apache for vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ....
    ProxyPass / http://host.com:9999/myapplication/?param=val
    ProxyPassReverse / http://host.com:9999/myapplication/?param=val

</VirtualHost>
```

3, Setup also VHost on port 9999

More info here:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html
- http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Comment: regarding point 3,: can you include in your answer how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Elaboration on the mod_proxy solution with `[P]`, the proxy flag:

1. Enable modules mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http:

   ```
   a2enmod proxy proxy_http
   ```

   Without these two enabled, you'd later get a 300 Forbidden status and the error message "AH00669: attempt to make remote request from mod_rewrite without proxy enabled" in the logs.
2. Place the following into the Apache2 vhost config section for the *forwarding* host:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:8080>
     …
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^$
     RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/
     RewriteRule  .*              -    [R=400,L]

     RewriteRule  (.*)  http://host.com:9999/myapplication/$1?param=val  [P,L]
     …
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   This includes a technique by Steve Webster to prevent malicious URL crafting, [explained here](http://statichtml.com/2011/mod_rewrite-proxy-caution.html). Not sure how to deal with appending the GET parameter in this context, though.
3. Restart Apache2:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```