# Apache redirect with a relative path

Tags: apache, redirect, reverse-proxy

I want to clear a doubt, it's possible in Apache to make "Alias" (Mask) to another port ??

Let I make a use of example:

In my Server I have Apache running in *:80 and another application running *:8080, Inside a domain called `www.example.com`.

So, What I'm think is if is possible and how can I do to make a "ALIAS" to if I use `www.example.com\other` to redirect to `www.example.com:8080\gui`.

And it is possible to mask this name to be `example.com\other`?

As said, I've enabled mod_proxy to use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

This was my first try with ProxyPass
`ProxyPass /foo http://domain.com:5780`
`ProxyPassReverse /foo http://domain.com:5780`

When I tried to access `http://myown.com/foo` it  redirected to the domain selected but did not loaded the images, I did not saw that before because the images are at the page bottom.

I have read some page about mod_rewrite, mod_alias, redirect and mod_proxy, I've edited my apache config and it's not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what application is running on port 8080.

- If it's a Java application running under Tomcat, consider [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/)
- If it's a Python WSGI application, consider [modwsgi in daemon mode](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).
- You could also use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) (eg. [Apache mod_rewrite internally to different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308088/apache-mod-rewrite-internally-to-different-port)).

Comment: It's not Java application because its not running with Tomcat, I don't know if is Python WSGI, but I will try mod_proxy, thanks.

Comment: I know that I said that it work, but only with a test that I did to another host in my network and did not appeared the images, I edit my main post with information.

Comment: Mod_proxy will forward the request to the other server and forward the response to the client. Your images and links are likely absolute to port 8080 and not relative to the base URL, so they will not work. Check the image links on the proxied page.

Comment: The problem is that the website is all coded with relative url.